# How can I include an unique sidebar content for each page with php

Tags: php

I'm working on a structure for my site and I have a problem with my sidebar. I would like to have an unique sidebar content for each page, but I don't know how I can do. I created a CSS folder to have my style.css, at the root, a file called index.php and template.php, a pages folder to group all my pages and in this folder, a file called index.php.

The index.php which is at the root has this content (It allows to define each content in each different page):

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET["p"]))
{
    $_GET["p"]="index";
}

if(!file_exists("pages/".$_GET["p"].".php"))
{
    $_GET["p"]="404";
}

ob_start();

include "pages/".$_GET["p"].".php";

$page_content = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

include "template.php";

?>
```

My template file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title><?= $page_title; ?></title>
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body id="<?= $page_id; ?>">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="#">Logo</a>
                    <p>Pellentesque in velit egestas, mattis metus vitae, hendrerit nunc. Nulla facilisi. Vestibulum at felis nec nunc ornare semper eu sit amet massa.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="navigation">
                <ul class="unstyled-list">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="home active">Accueil</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Utilisateurs</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Achats</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">À propos de nous</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="container">
            <?php if($sidebar): ?>
                <div id="main-sidebar-divider">
                    <div id="second-sidebar-divider">
            <?php endif; ?>
                <h1 class="page-title"><?= $page_title; ?></h1>
                <?= $page_content; ?>
            <?php if($sidebar): ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="sidebar">
                    <?= $sidebar_content; ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I have a variable $page_content. This allows me to have an unique content for each page, but for the sidebar, I don't know how I can do. To have a different content for each page, it's easy now. I just add what I want in my page like:

```
<?php 

$page_title = "Home";
$page_id = "home";
$sidebar = true;

?>

<p>CONTENT HERE FOR THE HOME</p>
```

And result: http://prntscr.com/a5vegt

You can see an error for the sidebar in the screen, because as you can see, I put a variable $sidebar_content. I would like to have a different sidebar content for each page. Just like:

```
<?php 

$page_title = "Home";
$page_id = "home";
$sidebar = true;

?>

CONTENT HERE FOR THE HOME

<div class="sidebar-container">
    <p>The sidebar content for the home page</p>
</div>
```

How I can do please?

Comment: Why not include a "sidebar.php" and do your randomness there? I.e with a switch case if you like.

Comment: where did you define `$sidebar_content`??

Comment: This is the problem, I would like to define the $sidebar_content, but I don't know how

Comment: `$sidebar_content = rand();`

Comment: What is it? I don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then why don't you put the html in the file like `sidebar.php`, and then use `include('sidebar.php');` where you want to put this??

template.php

```
<div id="sidebar">
  <?php include('sidebar.php'); ?>
</div>
```

sidebar.php

```
$sidebar_dir = 'sidebar_' . $_GET['p'] . '.php'; //e.g. sidebar_home.php
include($sidebar_dir);
```

Comment: Because this is not clean

Comment: Yes, but If I'm not on the home page? This is the home sidebar which will be displayed in the help.php page, for example. This is currently my problem. I need to have a different sidebar content for each page, not only one. Something of dynamic

Comment: you can have the sidebar.php to include the appropriate sidebar in turn.

Comment: Hi how I can do if my file are in a folder? Like: in my folder pages, help folder with the help.php and sidebar_help.php?

Comment: you mean your sidebar is in `help/sidebar_help`? you should create it's address... `$_GET['p'] . "/sidebar" . "_" . $_GET['p'] . ".php"` ...

Comment: Yes, this. Like: pages/help/help.php and sidebar_help.php